# getting dynamically added table rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am dynamically adding rows to a table that exists in a Jquery dialog. I want to clear all but first row of this table whenever the dialog is closed, so that if dialog is opened again only new set of rows is visible.

My objective is bring an empty table whenever this dialog is opened.

Here is my dialog code

```
$( "#personPmt" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 675,
    modal: true,
    position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: $("#pmtDetails") },
    close: function() {
      $('#personPmtTable').remove("tr:gt(0)");
     }
  });
```

And here is my dialog

```
<div id="personPmt" title="Personal Payment">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pmtEntry" id="personPmtTable">
        <tr>
          <th style="display:none">ID</th>
          <th class="cell_date">DOS</th>
          <th class="cell_code">CPT</th>
          <th class="cell_name">Description</th>
          <th class="cell_amt">Billed</th>
          <th class="cell_amt">Payment</th>
          <th class="cell_amt">Balance</th>
          <th class="cell_amt">New Balance</th>
        </tr>            
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Wrap your header in a `thead` element

```
<div id="personPmt" title="Personal Payment">
  <table class="pmtEntry" id="personPmtTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="display:none">ID</th>
        <th class="cell_date">DOS</th>
        <th class="cell_code">CPT</th>
        <th class="cell_name">Description</th>
        <th class="cell_amt">Billed</th>
        <th class="cell_amt">Payment</th>
        <th class="cell_amt">Balance</th>
        <th class="cell_amt">New Balance</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>        
  </table>
</div>
```

And then delete everything within `tbody` which will leave `thead` intact.

```
$("#personPmtTable tbody tr").remove();
```

Just make sure that you're appending new rows to `tbody`. :)

Comment: Thank you Robert. By using thead and tbody, I do not append rows but add html to table so that solves my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if my preposition to use `thead` and `tbody` helped you, but if it did, you can accept my answer. If you've come up with a completely different approach not outlined by any of our answers then you're welcome to provide your own answer and accept it after a few days. **It is important to accept some most valuable answer** because otherwise in time when you'll be asking new questions people will be reluctant to answer them as you're not doing your part within the community. Just FYI.

Comment: Thank you again! I am new user here, although I was enjoying help from outside for long time. I am overwhelmed with responses being received so quickly. Your answer guided me find a workaround. When I use thead and tbody I do not append or remove from tbody I just add whole set of rows every time. I would still need an answer to select rows added dynamically. When I check in firebug this selector shows blank array. I guess because rows have been added dynamically.

Comment: @bvnbhati: on the contrary. jQuery works on currently displayed DOM. So if your dynamically added rows are displayed, jQuery should see them. Maybe you should explain how you add those rows and where?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('#personPmt >  tr').not(':first').remove();
```

Comment: Problem here was as the contents have been added dynamically, no rows get removed in spite of using any selector.